# Activeadmin customize controller new action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Can anyone explain how I can customize the new action of Activeadmin controller? I've got classes like this: `Room`, `Option` and `RoomOption`. They are in `has_many through` association and I want to be able to build `RoomOptions` for each new `Room` based on `Options` present in the database.

I've got code like this:

```
controller do
    def new
      super
      Option.find_each { |option| resource.room_options.build(option: option)}
    end
end
```

But it doesn't work because no option is created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use:

```
def new
  build_resource
  Option.find_each { |option| resource.room_options.build(option: option) }
  new!
end
```

The room model must accept_nested_attributes for options.